# Selecting specific columns for CassandraRepository dynamically as per GrapqhQl query's return fields

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-cassandra, graphql-java

For the following graphql request:

```
query{testInput(testQueryInput:{xyz:"test"}){
        list{
        field1
        field2
        .
        .
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `CassandraRepository`'s findBy* methods.
This internally forms a `select * from tbl` query.

Is there a way to form the select query with only the the fields that are being passed in the graphql query's return section, dynamically? (This is to improve the existing performance as the DB has around 300 columns)
e.g:
`select field1, field2 from tbl`...

I prefer not using the **CqlSession** object and executing the query string.
Any suggestions customizing the CassandraRepository?